# how to observe `ProgressListener()` to show a progress bar while upload is in progress?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I am uploading a file to firestore using the following code and have a Progress Listener to track the upload status and what to show a progress bar while the upload is still in progress:

```kotlin
 var mReference =
            mStorage.reference.child(folder).child(uri!!.lastPathSegment!!)

        lateinit var uploadTask: UploadTask
        uploadTask = if (uri != null) {
            mReference.putFile(uri)
        } else {
            mReference.putBytes(data)
        }
```

This is what my `ProgressListener` looks like:

```kotlin
 try {
            uploadTask.addOnProgressListener { taskSnapshot ->
                val progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.bytesTransferred) / taskSnapshot.totalByteCount
                println("Uploading in progress :$progress% done")
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Toast.makeText(this, e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }
```

How should I make a progress bar appear and change with changing progress?

Comment: Btw you can merge the uploadTask variable since the if statement is exhaustive, and make it val `val uploadTask = if(...) {...} else {...}`.

Comment: Android povides you with a progress bar, see: [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar), you can use coroutines to change threads/goto Main thread to update the value on the progress bar, you'd probably use `withContext(Dispatchers.Main){}` or if you are on activity/fragment then can do `viewModelOwner.viewModelScope.launch{}`

Comment: @AnimeshSahu the if statement is already as you said, it is just spread over more lines for readability.